# Generate a random alphabet

Tags: java, android, random

How to generate a random number in android? In my activity , it has one `button`, `textView` and `editText`. The user firstly need to type an alphabet between A-D. When button is clicked, it will display an alphabet. **The alphabet should not same with the input**.

The alphabet will then deleted from the list.

Assume the list is {A,B,C,D} If user type A, the system will display any alphabet except A.  Let said the output is B, then B will deleted from the list. So if the button clicked again, it will not display B again.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final Random r = new Random();
        input=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        a=input.getText().toString();
        btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        Name=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  //if next button is clicked
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(a=="A") 
                {
                    //what should write here ? 
                }
                Name.setText(Integer.toString(r.nextInt(100) + 1));
            }
        });
    }
```

This is what I've tried, but it is used to generate a random number. Any hints ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest solution for you:

```
Random random = new Random();
int index = random.nextInt(25);

String [] alphabets = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L","M", "N","O","P","Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V","W", "X","Y","Z"};

String mRandomAlphabet = alphabets[index];
Log.i("Random Alphabet", mRandomAlphabet);
```

Hope this will help you sure.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete the input Alphabet from list and create an random index from that list, after that you get Alphabet by that index. Hope this help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use type casting for this:

1. Creating a array with ASCII number.
2. Type cast the input to int and remove that number from the array.
3. Then use random function to get any number from 0 to 26 i.e the length of alphabets and get that from the array list.
4. Now type cast it again to char and display it.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the alphabet from the list when user enters an alphabet and clicks on next. This way, you will never show the same alphabet.

1. Have 26 elements (alphabets) in an arrayList.
2. Generate a random number between 0 to n (n being 25 initially).
3. Get the list item at that index. It will be an alphabet.
4. Remove it from the list.
5. Generate a random number between 0 and n-1.
6. Repeat.

Pro: Works with a number of variations. Not just with alphabets.